# Implement multi language with angularjs & .net

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multilingual

In Hebrew one need to call another in one of the two manners: towards a man or a woman.

I have an angularjs project with .net on the server side. It works as a WebApp.

I want it to read strings from an XML file and display them when necessary. There will be 2 files - one for each gender (and the in the future, maybe some other languages as English & Russian).

What is the best way to do so? I will save the required display method (hebrew-men, hebrew-women, english, russian, etc...) in a localStorage object.

I need a minimum of server-side calls as to save on bandwidth, and for the calls from the files to be as fast a possible.

Comment: Check out [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate).